# ArrayList.containsAll does not use my custom equals function

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, junit

The following code is a JUnit test function which fails upon execution.

```
List<KGramPostingsEntry> a = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
List<KGramPostingsEntry> b = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
KGramPostingsEntry entry = new KGramPostingsEntry(1);
a.add(entry);

entry = new KGramPostingsEntry(1);
b.add(entry);

assertTrue(a.containsAll(b));
```

It uses the `KGramPostingsEntry` class:

```
package ir;

public class KGramPostingsEntry {
    int tokenID;

    public KGramPostingsEntry(int tokenID) {
        this.tokenID = tokenID;
    }

    public KGramPostingsEntry(KGramPostingsEntry other) {
        this.tokenID = other.tokenID;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return tokenID + "";
    }
    public boolean equals(KGramPostingsEntry other) {
        if(other.tokenID == this.tokenID) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an `equals()` function in the class that compares the `tokenID` of the different `KGramPostingsEntry` objects. It seems to me that this function is not used when calling `containsAll()` in the test. Further experimentation seems to verify this to be true:

```
List<KGramPostingsEntry> a = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
List<KGramPostingsEntry> b = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
KGramPostingsEntry entry = new KGramPostingsEntry(1);
a.add(entry);
b.add(entry);

assertTrue(a.containsAll(b));
```

Here, I'm inserting the same object in both lists. This test **does not fail**. As far as I've gathered, `ArrayList` makes a copy object of the object sent to `add()`, before storing a reference to that object. This means that the objects in the two `List`s are not the same (even though they have the same `tokenID`), and that `containsAll()` does not check for object reference equality. But if it does not check for object reference equality and does not check the `equals()` function defined in my code, what does it check? The only plausible option to me is that it checks for object **value** equality, and that the two objects stored in the first test example are *somehow* different (even though their only property is `tokenID`, which is the same in both objects).

What is going on here? How can I make this test succeed the way I want it to?

Comment: Don't forget to implement a `hashCode()` when you implement `equals()`

Comment: You should include, @Override that way your compiler will warn you when you make this mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the `equals` declaration of `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))). You're trying to *override* this method, but instead you *overloaded* it:

```
public boolean equals(KGramPostingsEntry other)
```

Notice how the argument type in your method is `KGramPostingsEntry`, which differs from the argument type in `Object.equals`, namely `Object`. When a method has the same name but different argument types, it is overloaded, not overridden.

When the `ArrayList` tries to compare its contents with `equals`, it'll use the most applicable overridden version of `Object.equals`. That unfortunately doesn't include your method.

Luckily the fix is easy: you need to implement your `equals` method with an `Object` argument:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null || !(obj instanceof KGramPostingsEntry)) {
        return false;
    }
    KGramPostingsEntry other = (KGramPostingsEntry) obj;
    if(other.tokenID == this.tokenID) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that annotating the method with `@Override` will catch this error.  This is, in fact, exactly what the annotation is for.

Answer (score 4):

The equals method doesn't have the correct signature. It should be

```
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on why it has to have that signature?

Comment: @Sahand otherwise it is a different method and this one does not get called by the implementation of List to establish whether List contains the object. List will call `this.equals(Object obj2)` which comes inherited from `Object` class as you had not overrode it.